# If all fields for a column are null, OpenSearch does not include that field, and so sorting on that field fails

Tags: sorting, null, opensearch

When adding sorting configuration for data in OpenSearch, I came across a situation where the data's field that I want to sort on had only null values. OpenSearch return an error that says `[query_shard_exception] Reason: No mapping found for [MY_NULL_FIELD] in order to sort on`. That being said, if I add ONE value, then the sort functions as expected. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If field values are all `null` in all documents, the field probably does not exist in the mapping. Using `unmapped_type` in the sort query should work.

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "some_missing_field": {
        "order": "asc",
        "unmapped_type" : "long"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've also come across a similar solution by adding "ignore_unmmaped" : true

Answer (score 0):

You can define `null_value` [properties](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/null-value.html) while configuring index mapping.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "status_code": {
        "type":       "keyword",
        "null_value": "NULL" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please consider below while configuring null value.

> The null_value needs to be the same data type as the field. For
> instance, a long field cannot have a string null_value.